# Is there a best practice when returning a list of images from an ASP.NET Web API

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api

I'm creating a Web API (on .NET) and I have to return a list of images, not the urls to the image because I don't have them.

Is it a good idea to return 10-20 images as base64 in my response? Even though the pictures will be very small I'm thinking that may be too much data for the api response, any ideas?

Comment: return url should be a good practice when browser sending requests to your api, in my opinion. If the request coming from an application which may request to your api to get images and store the images, then returning base64 string is ok, but in this scenario, you don't need to convert the images to base64 first...

Comment: Provide a `limit` query string parameter that allows the client to specify the number of image resources to be returned. The bounds (`min` & `max`) are really down to you. I suggest profiling how your API performs and then make an informed decision.

Comment: Another option, if you do not want to store the images and generate a url, is to save the base64 list in a file, save that, and return that url to the front end.  That way you don't care as much about the size going out of your api.